# How to add remove in each item of select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2, I want to remove icon in each item.

[image]

I did try by adding the allowClear: true property, but not able to achieve it.

```
     <select class="select2 form-control mb-3 custom-select form-control-red" id="drpMake"  title="Make" style="height: 36px;" required="required">
                        </select>
```

```
  $('drpMake').select2({
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true,
    });
```

Comment: `allowClear` means clear the selected value - so you select "1" then you get a [x] next to that selected value and the selection goes back to *blank*.    It appears you're trying to *remove* an option, which isn't an option [see what I did there] in the select2 options/methods.

Comment: You need to ad a custom `templateResult` within which you add a HTML including your `[x]` "clear" (remove) button - then add an event handler to that button which removes the `option` from the underlying `select` - don't forget to then refresh/update the select2 to reflect the updated `select` options